# Windows 10 shows old / previous notification

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I have noticed the following behavior on my Windows 10 install and wondered if I perhaps have something misconfigured or whether this was by design:

If there are unacknowledged notifications in the Windows 10 Notification Center and a new notification arrives, Windows displays the previous notification, waits for it to auto-hide, then displays the new notification and waits for it to auto-hide.

For example, if I receive an email, Outlook will display a notification with the subject of the email and a short preview of the email body.  This notification will be displayed in the corner for a moment, and will auto-dismiss in around 5 seconds.

After the Outlook notification is auto-hidden, I receive a Slack message.  Windows will show the Outlook notification, wait 5 seconds for it to auto-hide, then show the Slack notification.  The Slack notification then auto-hides after another 5-second delay.

The next time a notification arrives, the Slack message will be displayed and auto-dismissed before the real new notification is displayed.

This behavior is consistent and occurs each time a new notification is displayed.  It means that in order to see what the new notification is, I either have to wait for the previous notification to show and disappear, or I have to jump to my mouse to dismiss the previous notification to reveal the actual new notification.

The only way to avoid it appears to be to either manually acknowledge notifications as they arrive, or periodically clear out the notification center.  Or, simply disabling notifications.

Does anyone else see this same behavior, or is it just something that's wrong with my Windows 10 installation?

Comment: Have you tried running `SFC /SCANNOW`?

Comment: Result: "Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Comment: My laptop does this 100% of the time. It's...very annoying. Especially with Slack notifications. I don't have a fix for it, unfortunately.

Comment: I have this problem as well. Any luck in resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

This is not common for Windows 10. I can confirm this because I have three different installations on different PCs, and am experiencing the same issue you described on only one of my installations.

I'm not sure what the fix for this is. I can't seem to find other instances on the web.

It’s super inconvenient when I receive an Outlook notification, but then see a previous notification prior to seeing the actual notification.

*Edit*
I understand that this does not resolve OP's problem (which is something I'm facing as well), it does answer one of his questions ("Does anyone else see this same behavior, or is it just something that's wrong with my Windows 10 installation?")

Comment: I understand that this does not resolve OP's problem (which is something I'm facing as well), it does answer his question:
 "Does anyone else see this same behavior, or is it just something that's wrong with my Windows 10 installation?"

I'm unable to leave a comment on OP due to lack of reputation.

Comment: I've been experiencing it for a few months now as well.